# How to use Func<T> & Linq with .NET framework 3.0

Tags: .net, wpf, func

I've been developing a WPF application with .NET framework 3.5 and later had to change to 3.0. Some of the features like `Func<T>` (System.Core.dll) and Linq is not available now and VS throws compile errors to my existing code. How can I use 3.5 features in 3.0?

Comment: Why can't you stick to version 3.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: [How to Use .NET 3.5 Features and C# 3.0 Syntax in .NET 2.0?](http://abdullin.com/how-to-use-net-35-syntax-and-compiler-features-for-net-20/).

Here are the steps:

1. Referencing LinqBridge
2. Referencing System.Core
3. Implementing features yourself

Comment: Are those steps or alternatives?  I haven't looked at it, but I figured `LinqBridge` would do it all.